# Why 'break' in nested condition block creates 1 more iteration in while loop in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm testing a multi-threading code piece. I'm trying to wrap C++ thread as a new class to bind with given function with additional parameters to run it under certain frequency and optionally repeat or not.

The weird thing I met is that 1 statement in while loop seems to be run after it exited the while loop.

```cpp
// timer_main.cc

#include <functional>
#include <atomic>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <thread>
#include <unordered_map>

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class TimerThread
{
public:
    explicit TimerThread(const function<void()>& task): repeat_(false), running_(false), task_(task) {}
    ~TimerThread() { StopTimer(); }

public:
    bool StartTimer(uint64_t interval_ms, bool repeat = true) {
        if (thread_.get_id() == this_thread::get_id()) return false;
        if (running_) return false;
        repeat_ = repeat;
        running_ = true;
        thread_ = thread([this, interval_ms]() {
            while (running_)
            {
                {
                    unique_lock<mutex> lock(mutex_);
                    cv_timer_.wait_for(lock, chrono::milliseconds(interval_ms), [this] {
                        return !running_;
                    });
                }

                if (!running_)
                {
                    return;
                }

                task_();

                if (!repeat_) {
                    return;
                }
            } // end while
        }); // end thread_
        return true;
    }

    bool StopTimer() {
        cout << "StopTimer!" << endl;
        if (thread_.get_id() == this_thread::get_id()) {
          cout << "same thread id, return false"; return false;
        }
        running_ = false;
        cv_timer_.notify_one();
        cout << "waiting for timer thread to join..." << endl;
        if (thread_.joinable()) {
            thread_.join();
        } else {
            cout << "timer thread is not joinable" << endl;
        }
        cout << "timer stopped. this thread id: " << this_thread::get_id() << endl;
        return true;
    }
private:
    atomic<bool> repeat_;
    atomic<bool> running_;
    function<void()> task_;
    mutex mutex_;
    condition_variable cv_timer_;
    thread thread_;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    shared_ptr<TimerThread> tt0 = make_shared<TimerThread>([&]{ cout << "hello" << endl; });
   
    tt0->StartTimer(1000, true);

    while (true) {
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(2000));
        tt0->StopTimer();
        break;
    }
    cout << "exit while loop" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

My expected output is

```
❯ ./timer_main
hello
hello
StopTimer!
waiting for timer thread to join...
timer stopped. this thread id: 0x113d04600
exit while loop
```

However, I got following

```
❯ ./timer_main
hello
StopTimer!
waiting for timer thread to join...
hello
timer stopped. this thread id: 0x113d04600
exit while loop
StopTimer!
waiting for timer thread to join...
timer thread is not joinable
timer stopped. this thread id: 0x113d04600
```

According to the output, the `StopTimer` was called 2 times, and the 2nd time is outside the while loop..., I don't know why.

Any help would be highly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: How many times do you expect a `while (true)` loop to execute, before it finishes? Also, it's fairly obvious that the shown code is not real code that shows this behavior, because it won't even compile.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik although interestingly it did emit the 'exit while loop' message

Comment: Because, @pm100, I just noticed that the shown code is fake code that won't even compile.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik me too - OP please post the real code

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks for pointing out. I miss copy/past the code. Already updated.

Comment: Nope - still doesnt compile

Comment: Your 2nd call to `StopTimer` comes from the destructor. VTC as a typo.

Comment: It was easy to overlook. You know how I found it? I simply used a debugger and set a breakpoint, then I could easily see where both calls came from. This is what a debugger is for. If you don't know how to use it, time to learn that?

Comment: @SamVarshavshik exactly. I should put more effort on debugger. Thanks.

Comment: @Qiao debugging is the #1 skill a programmer should have and the skill they should strive to use the least (because of testing)